# MariaDB no crea función

Tags: sql, mariadb

estoy haciendo una función en MariaDB pero me marca un error de Sintaxis.... y honestamente ahora si desconozco que parte es... pongo la función, dice que es en la línea 6 en el DECLARE =S pero ahora si no se porque =S

```
CREATE FUNCTION ReferenciaGaby( referencia VARCHAR(22)
) RETURNS VARCHAR(22) DETERMINISTIC

BEGIN

    DECLARE sn VARCHAR(22);
    DECLARE s1 VARCHAR(1);
    DECLARE s2 VARCHAR(1);

    SET s1 = SUBSTRING(referencia,3,1);


    IF s1 <> '6' THEN
        SET sn = referencia;

    ELSEIF s1 = '6' THEN
        SET s2 = SUBSTRING(referencia,9,2);

        IF s2 IS NOT IN ('00','MI', 'CO') THEN
            SET sn = referencia;
        END IF;

    END IF;


    RETURN sn;


END;
```

Comment: ¿No te falta cambiar el `DELIMITER`? ¿Desde dónde estas corriendo el script?

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Declara el `DELMITER` al inicio de tu función así: `DELIMITER //` y luego al final  cierra el delimiter así: `END // DELIMITER ;`

Comment: Declara el DELMITER al inicio de tu función así: DELIMITER // y luego al final cierra el delimiter así: END // DELIMITER ;  pues el motor de bases de datos interpreta el `;` como el termino de una sentencia, por eso mientras la función esta siendo creada se cambia el `;` por `//` y hasta el momento del termino del cuerpo de la función se invoca nuevamente a `;` para establecer que ahi termina la estructura completa de dicha función.